# TensorFlowJS model converted from GoogleColab has different probabilities values in prediction result (using angular with tfjs)

Tags: angular, prediction, tensorflow.js

I'm new to TensorFlowJS. I've used the Google Colab to create and train a model using TensorFlow Lite Model Maker, convert it to a TFJS, and then use it in an angular application.

In the colab, the model achieved high acuracity. I've saved the model using:

```
model.export(export_dir='.', export_format=ExportFormat.SAVED_MODEL);
```

and then I use

```
tfjs.converters.convert_tf_saved_model('saved_model','tfjsconvertido');
```

in order to obtain the tfjs. In the angular, i'm using:

```
async fazerPrevisao(modelo: tf.GraphModel){    
const batched = tf.tidy(() => {      
    const im = new Image();
    im.src = this.foto.webviewPath;
    im.height = 224;
    im.width = 224;        
    const imagem = tf.cast(tf.browser.fromPixels(im).reshape([-1,224,224,3]),'float32');        
    
  this.prediction = modelo.predict(imagem);
  this.prediction.print();
 });
}
```

The result in angular differs too much from Colab. In some cases, the result label is not correct, and even getting the right label, the values of probabilities are completely different. What could it be?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
im.height = 224;
im.width = 224;
```

The image may not be resized properly. `tf.image.resizeBilinear` can be used for resizing.

```
const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear(tf.browser.fromPixels(im), [224, 224]).expandDims()
```

It could also be that the image has not completely loaded when it is used

```
function load(url){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const im = new Image()
        im.crossOrigin = 'anonymous'
        im.src = 'url'
        im.onload = () => {
          resolve(im)
        }
   })
}

const image = await load(url)
let tensor = await tf.browser.fromPixels(image)

const resized = tf.image.resizeBilinear (tensor, [224, 224]).expandDims()
```

The resized tensor can now be used for the prediction

Comment: I've tried to use this but didn't work. In fact, if i change the values in height and width the prediction doesn't work, wich shows that the image is been loaded. In addition, when i try to use tf.image.resizeBilinear, it returns a tf.Tensor3D and the GraphModel.predict needs a tf.Tensor.

Comment: In the first case, changing the height and width to 100, for example, the error message is: "The implicit shape can't be a fractional number. Got 30000 / 150528". When i put 224 in both, the predict works. And when i use tf.image.resizeBilinear, the message error is: "The shape of dict['input_1'] provided in model.execute(dict) must be [-1,224,224,3], but was [224,224,3]"

Comment: You need to expand the first dimension either with `tf.expandDims` or reshape the tensor with `tf.reshape`. See updated answer

Comment: I've changed the code with tf.expandDims and worked, but the probability values ​​are still wrong. I will continue investigating. Thank you very much for all your attention so far.

Comment: Could it be that you are doing some extra processing in python than just simply resizing ?

Comment: In google colab i just use model.export(export_dir='.', export_format=ExportFormat.SAVED_MODEL); and then tfjs.converters.convert_tf_saved_model('saved_model','tfjsconvertido'); After that, I use the converted TFJS in angular. I'm not using Python without the Google Colab.

Comment: Is it possible that the tfjs.converters is not converting the model correctly? I also suspected about the version of TensorFlowJS that i'm using, but in angular i just call import "import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'", after install it by npm install

Comment: So, after searching about other alternatives, i've found the https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image and the model that i've trained and exported worked in angular. It was necessary import the @teachablemachine/image and modify the code, but it is more simple now and the results are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a alternative to the problem changing the model exported. I've found the https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/train/image and there i've trained and exported the model to TFJS. In angular, i've installed the @teachablemachine/image and then changed the code in order to use this aproach:

```
...

import * as tmImage from '@teachablemachine/image';

...
model: tmImage.CustomMobileNet;
predictions: any;

const modelURL = 'URL/model.json';
const metadataURL = 'URL/metadata.json';

this.model = await tmImage.load(modelURL, metadataURL);

await this.fazerPrevisao(this.model);

async fazerPrevisao(modelo: tmImage.CustomMobileNet){
const im = new Image();
im.src = PATHOFTHEPHOTO;
im.height = 224;
im.width = 224;              
this.predictions = await this.model.predict(im,true);
console.log('Previsão: ',this.predictions);
}
```

the Probabilities now are pretty good. Thanks @edkeveked for the help!